# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: angular, http, express, heroku, electron

I am try to convert my electron app to full web. when I am running the app from my localhost I get this error:

> Failed to load https://agrt.herokuapp.com/login: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

on my client I sent a http request with:

```
this.http.post(Consts.REMOTE_URL + '/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }, {withCredentials:true}).
```

on my server I use cors ant I set:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Accept');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    })
```

**my server is on heroku.**

when I am running from the electron everything going well.

please, any help will be great!

the server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const winston = require('winston')
const db = require('./db')
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config()

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
require('./config/passport')(passport, db)
require('./config/express')(app, passport, db.pool, db)
require('./app/routes')(app, passport)

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.message && (~err.message.indexOf('not found'))) {
    return next()
  }
  winston.error(err.stack)
  return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error on backend occurred.'})
})

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening to port: "+port);
  if(app.get('env') === 'test') return

  winston.log('Express app started on port ' + port)
})

server.on('close', () => {
  winston.log('Closed express server')

  db.pool.end(() => {
    winston.log('Shut down connection pool')
  })
})
```

the express.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')
const session = require('express-session')
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session)
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const winston = require('winston')
const config = require('./')
const resumable = require('../app/lib/resumablejs')
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

module.exports = (app, passport, pool, db) => {
    let log = 'dev'
    if (env !== 'development') {
    log = {
      stream: {
        write: message => winston.info(message)
      }
    }
  }

    if (env !== 'test') app.use(morgan(log))

    app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars())
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(expressValidator())

    app.use(methodOverride(function (req) {
        if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
            var method = req.body._method
            delete req.body._method
            return method
        }
    }))

    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(session({
        store: new pgSession({
            pool
        }),
        secret: config.session_secret,
        // saveUninitialized: false,
        // resave: false,
         cookie: { maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
    }))

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    app.use(function(req,res,next){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Accept');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    })
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(passport.session())

    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')))
    app.use('/files', resumable(undefined, undefined, db))
}
```

Comment: If you check in the browsers developer tools, what headers are coming back from your server when you make that call? (Both from the actual call, and the OPTIONS preflight)

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 08 Jul 2018 12:44:57 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!!

Comment: So as per the error, your `access-control-allow-origin` header is set to `*`, not `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: how can I change it ?

Comment: You'll need to post the full server JS file. Something in there is over writing your header values.

Comment: I try to add to the server side the ' res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:4200");' but it doesn't help..

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full code from that file?

Comment: I am using passport.js . it could be the problem?

Comment: on the client I get thie error: 'Failed to load https://agrt.herokuapp.com/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.'

Comment: Remove `app.use(cors())`. It's overriding your values, and it seems it's not compatible with `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true`

Comment: now it change the error to: 'Failed to load https://agrt.herokuapp.com/login: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.'

Comment: That error makes it sound like you're sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your request, i.e. from your frontend, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: you right. I remove that, and now I get thos errors:- POST https://agrt.herokuapp.com/login 503 (Service Unavailable)
and - Failed to load https://agrt.herokuapp.com/login: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503. and on the server side I get the error :Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: That means something is trying to send a response before your headers have been added, but I can't really tell where it's happening, unless it's the line with `res.status(500)`

Comment: I found the place that send a response. thank you so much!! I spend a lot of time on this!!!

Comment: I try to run my app on localhost and it succeeding, but when I try to run on remote server the http request fails again. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because you set the value of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to localhost, so when your run on the remote server the URL is no longer localhost and therefore no longer allowed

Comment: No, I change it to : res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',req.headers.origin);

Comment: the request is executed , but the cookies are not allowed..

Comment: Its happen only on chrome. I checked my setting and it seems to be ok..

Answer (score 0):

Try using following configuration:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  if ("OPTIONS" == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or If you are using CORS middleware and you want to send withCredentials boolean true (for example sending responses with set-cookie headers) , you can configure CORS like this:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
 //update: or "origin: true," if you don't wanna add a specific one
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

- for using credentials app.use(corse()) won't work, you should specify your specific origin(s) in corsOptions.

---

it is (somehow) equal to setting the response headers like this:

```
app.all("*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});
```