# Reason for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' error

Tags: cors

I have a server that exposes some resources, and sends back the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

This is needed because the server contains static resources that are accessed by various webapps and dev environments throughout our intranet, which are all different origins.

This worked correctly until recently, but now it stopped. Now, if we try to access any of the resources from any origin, we receive the error:

```
Failed to load http://foo/bar/res: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://devenv06:4589' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute
```

So, I've tried adding my origins manually, like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://devenv01,http://devenv02,http://prodserver
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

but now I receive the error:

```
Failed to load http://foo/bar/res: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values, but only one is allowed
```

This basically makes the server unusable, since I need multiple origins.

So, what I want to know is:

- Is this something new that browsers introduced, or did something change on the server? Why did it work before with that configuration and now it doesn't? (client code didn't change...)
- Is there a general solution instead of having to manually set every possible origin?

Comment: Probably duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231699/access-control-allow-origin-header-in-the-response-must-not-be-the-wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something new that browsers introduced, or did something change on the server?

It is not a new requirement in the spec.

> Is there a general solution instead of having to manually set every possible origin?

Write logic that reads the `Origin` *request* header, then uses that value to generate the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` *response* header.

Usually you will want to pass it through a whitelist first, otherwise, you are giving permission to `evil-hacker.example.com` to make requests to your server from the browsers of people logged into your site, with all the credentials needed to prove they are who they say they are. That would probably be a massive security problem and render having credentials in the first place pointless.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server software is not developed by us, it's a third party product, I can set custom response headers in the settings, but not dynamically as you suggest. I guess they introduced this restriction in recent versions and I will have to contact them for support at this point. Thanks.

Comment: (I've unmarked your answer because I noticed my workaround wasn't actually working, I edited the question, keeping it open to see if someone can explain this "only one origin allowed" further...)

Comment: @Master_T — As this answer says, you have to dynamically set the allowed origin based on the Origin request header. You were trying to set a hardcoded comma-separated list … which this answer does not suggest (because you can't).

Comment: So basically, if I can't change the server's code I'm screwed... ok thanks.

Comment: You can write Apache configuration, so you can change the server's code (even if that involves writing a middleware in mod_perl). You might even be able to do this with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not apache, it's part of a third-party tool which does not provide further configuration options. I'll have to contact the manufacturer. Thanks anyway